# Is there a nice(r) way of writing this Template Haskell code involving singleton data types?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I've just started to use Template Haskell (I've finally got a use case, yay!) and now I'm cognitively stuck.

What I'm trying to do is generating a singleton datatype declaration of the form

```
data $V = $V deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

starting from a name `V` (hopefully starting with an uppercase character!). To be explicit, I'm trying to write a function `declareSingleton` of type `String -> DecsQ` (I should mention here I'm using GHC 7.6.1, template-haskell version 2.8.0.0) such that the splice

```
$(declareSingleton "Foo")
```

is the equivalent of

```
data Foo = Foo deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

---

I've got the following code working and doing what I want, but I'm not very happy with it:

```
declareSingleton :: String -> Q [Dec]
declareSingleton s = let n = mkName s in sequence [
        dataD (cxt []) n [] [normalC n []] [''Eq,''Ord]
   ]
```

I was hoping to get something like the following to work:

```
declareSingleton :: String -> Q [Dec]
declareSingleton s = let n = mkName s in 
    [d| data $n = $n deriving (Eq,Ord) |]
```

I've tried, to no avail (but not exhaustively!), various combinations of `$s`, `$v`, `$(conT v)`, `v`, `'v` so I have to suppose my mental model of how Template Haskell works is too simplistic.

Am I missing something obvious here, am I confusing type names and constructor names in some essential way, and can I write `declareSingleton` in a nice(r) way?

If so, how; if not, why not?

(Side remark: the Template Haskell API changes rapidly, and I'm happy for that - I want this simple type to eventually implement a multi-parameter type class with an associated type family - but the churn the API is currently going through doesn't make it easy to search for tutorials! There's a huge difference how TH was implemented in 6.12.1 or 7.2 (when most of the existing tutorial were written) versus how it works nowadays...)

Comment: It would be lovely if there were an extensive TH "cookbook" document that was versioned along with the code. I would say be happy that you got something that works, and hope you never ever have to revisit it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Template Haskell documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html):

> A splice can occur in place of
>
> - an expression; the spliced expression must have type Q Exp
> - an type; the spliced expression must have type Q Typ
> - a list of top-level declarations; the spliced expression must have type Q [Dec]

So e.g. constructor names simply cannot be spliced in the current version of Template Haskell.

I don't think there's much you can do to simplify this use-case (barring constructing the whole declaration as a string and transforming it into a `Dec` via [`toDec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-meta/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Meta-Syntax-Translate.html#v%3atoDec) in [`haskell-src-meta`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta)).

You might consider simply binding the different parts of the declaration to local variables. While more verbose, it makes the code a bit easier to read.

```
declareSingleton :: String -> Q [Dec]
declareSingleton s = return [DataD context name vars cons derives] where
    context  = []
    name     = mkName s
    vars     = []
    cons     = [NormalC name fields]
    fields   = []
    derives  = [''Eq, ''Ord]
```

Answer (score 0):

a hack that parses an interpolated string rather than constructing the AST:

```
makeU1 :: String -> Q [Dec]
makeU1 = makeSingletonDeclaration >>> parseDecs >>> fromRight >>> return

makeSingletonDeclaration :: String -> String
makeSingletonDeclaration name = [qq|data {name} = {name} deriving (Show)|]
```

where:

```
parseDecs :: String -> Either String [Dec]
```

usage:

```
makeU1 "T"
main = print T
```

it needs these packages:

```
$ cabal install haskell-src-exts
$ cabal install haskell-src-meta
$ cabal install interpolatedstring-perl6
```

runnable script:

https://github.com/sboosali/haskell/blob/0794eb7a52cf4c658270e49fa4f0d9e53c4b0ebf/TemplateHaskell/Splice.hs